# Can I play cross-platform multiplayer?

Tags: exploding-kittens

The game's description states that I can play online with my friends and with strangers.

[image: "play online with friends and strangers"]

I have an Android phone and my sister has an iPad, I wonder if we can play together.

Can I play cross-platform multiplayer?

Comment: I mean the app btw, not the tabletop: http://www.explodingkittens.com/app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer to your question... Straight off their Wikipedia page:

"In April 2016, the mobile version was also released onto the Android platform, and allowed for cross-platform play between all mobile versions"

So I would definitely say that yes, you can play with your sister if she has the IPad!